# Proper way to package a library so that it imports correctly without leading package name

Tags: python, pypi

I am attempting to release a package to PyPI, but encountering an issue with imports.

My package is set up like this:

```
mypackage/
    setup.py
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        mypackage.py
```

In `mypackage.py`, I have a class: `MyPackageWrapper` and the `__init__.py` is empty.

During development, I was doing this:

```
from mypackage import MyPackageWrapper
```

This worked. However, I made my initial release to PyPI and the above no longer works. It errors with `ImportError: cannot import name MyPackageWrapper`

I have to have an import like this:

```
from mypackage.mypackage import MyPackageWrapper
```

or

```
import mypackage
mypackage.mypackage.MyPackageWrapper()
```

How can I get rid of the leading `mypackage` in both of the above, so that I can use either:

```
from mypackage import MyPackageWrapper    # As done in development, or

import mypackage
mypackage.MyPackageWrapper()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__init__.py` file should contain:

```
from mypackage.mypackage import MyPackageWrapper
```